# Is it possible to listen for system language change in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to listen when the user changes their system language? I need to clear some list when the user changes their language. Now I am detecting the language in the `void main()` function on startup.

```dart
void main() async {
  // Firebase Push Notifications initialization
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
  detectLanguageChange();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);


  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeLocales(List<Locale>? locales) {
    // TODO: implement didChangeLocales
    super.didChangeLocales(locales);

    print("Locales changed");
  }
```

It needs to run 'detectLanguage' every time the language changes.

Comment: `WidgetsBindingObserver.didChangeLocales` - the docs say: *"Called when the system tells the app that the user's locale has changed. For example, if the user changes the system language settings."*

Comment: Hey thanks! I am trying to get the syntax right but it does not fit: WidgetsBindingObserver().didChangeLocales((locale) {

  });

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61958437/flutter-widgets-binding-observer or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64999808/get-widget-observer-for-widgetsbindingobserver

Comment: I don't see them using didChangeLocales. Do I need to make a new 'widget'  and extend it with WidgetsBindingObserver?

Comment: just mixin `WidgetsBindingObserver` with some of your classes (with `with WidgetsBindingObserver` syntax), call `WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this)` and override methods you want to "watch"

Comment: I added some code, but I still do not get what you mean... :/

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64999877/2252830)  you can see how to add observer inside `initState` method

Comment: I added it in the init state, but how can I execute a function when the language changes? I edited the question again and added the code

Comment: override `didChangeLocales` method in `_MyAppState` class then

Comment: I did that and it works (partly). Now the print method is fired when the user goes back to the app. Is it possible to fire a method at the moment, the language is changed?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create a stateful widget which acts as a `WidgetsBindingObserver` and receive locale changes by the `didChangeLocales` callback.

Let me provide a minimal example widget:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LocaleListenerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Locale defaultLocale;
  final Widget? child;
  
  const LocaleListenerWidget({super.key, this.defaultLocale = const Locale('en_US'), this.child});

  @override
  State<LocaleListenerWidget> createState() => _LocaleListenerWidgetState();
}

class _LocaleListenerWidgetState extends State<LocaleListenerWidget>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeLocales(List<Locale>? locales) {
    super.didChangeLocales(locales);

    // Here locales is a list of all the locales enabled on the device.
    // Like: [Locale('en_US'), Locale('ar_SA')]

    // The first locale is the phone's main locale, but in reality you should
    // traverse until you find a supported locale.
    final currentLocale = locales?.first ?? widget.defaultLocale;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child ?? const SizedBox.shrink();
  }
}
```

Then you just have to put this widget high enought in your tree. For example into your `MaterialApp`'s `builder`:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(builder: (context, child) => const LocaleListenerWidget(child: child)));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible. Take a look on this example:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);

_customFunction();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: 'Title'),
      ),
      body: Text(myLocale.languageCode == 'fr' ? 'Bonjour!' : 'Hello!'),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is it possible to execute a function every time the language changes?

Comment: this works for me thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Getx` library and use:

```
return GetMaterialApp(
     locale: Get.deviceLocale,   //returns Locale('<language code>', '<country code>')
);
```

from there you can store it in a variable and once the device language update changes so does the var and there you link your desired function.

Comment: Don't use Getx if all you want to do is listen to locale change.